# Java- check if id already exists in database

Tags: java, database

I am trying to log in with a name and an ID in a JTextField after a ButtonClick. After the first log in all the users are stored in the database.
What I am trying to do is: If the user is already stored in the database I want to show the message ("Welcome back") but what I got at the moment is *"Duplicate entry '11' for key 'PRIMARY'*. I want to "ignrore that" because if a user is stored in the database it should have the possibility to log in again and continue for the next page. And if a user is new, I will show a JOptionPane ("Welcome new user")

What I tried so far:
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"already exist");
                        }

```
                String query1 = "SELECT * FROM user";
                PreparedStatement pst1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
                ResultSet r1= pst1.executeQuery();
            if(....)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"...");} 
                    else if(r1.next()) {
                        if (r1.getString("ID").equals(txtFieldID.getText())) {
```

Thx all in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you tried that?  Because it doesn't compile.

Comment: Please add SQL queries as well.

Comment: Really?? so yes, it throws an exception but it worked. But it does not show the JOptionPane ("already exist") I think my code is definitely wrong :D

Comment: @TimurLevadny edit

Answer (score 1):

You should first execute a query to validate that the ID already exists in database so in that case you'll only get one result: `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS WHERE ID = ?`. If the result of that query returns a value greater than 0 then the user exists and you show the message.

You should't query the whole table and then iterate each row to do that kind of validation.

Comment: thx for your answer. Is it something  like      `if(rs.next()) > 0 {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("User exist")}` ?

Comment: Yes, that could work too, but in that case you should change the `COUNT` for just ID. If you keep the count then you should cast the result to Integer.